# Wordpress core update error (Core obsolete)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site that i did't update for over 6 months, now i have a warning in my theme saying core obsolete. image for you to understand better.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the Wordpress core, that is actually Woocommerce which is a plugin to make the webiste an e-commerce.

You shouldn't worry much about those but if you want to be 100% sure that everything is ok just make this easy thing: for each one of the files that woocommerce is telling you (you can see their relative path in the screenshot) compare them to their respective original file which are located in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates.

To make the notice go away all you have to do is changing the " @version 4.3.0" which is a piece of code inside a comment block at the beginning of each file (or add it back in your theme's copy if they are missing). As soon as woocommerce matches the @versions tag, the warning will go away

As an extra step you could check if the new updated templates inside  /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates contains some new code/different functions that you may need to update aswell. It's hard to tell what exactly you have to do because the theme's custom file may vary from project to project.

IMPORTANT SIDENOTE: If the files are in your parent theme (so you don't have a child theme) then this procedure it's **HIGLY DISCOURAGED**. You should first create a child-theme (https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and do the same thing or just wait that your theme's author release an update

Comment: do you know how to upload the file back to wordpress ? please

Comment: You would need to setup an FTP using a client of your choice like FileZilla. That would require you to have the host name to connect to, the port (default is 21 but some provider can change it), username and password. If you are missing those information you can request to your hosting provider

Comment: Thank you so much, i tell you in the few days if it work, bye